# Determining Bids in a Trick Taking Card Game Probalistically

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

I am attempting to design a simplistic AI to play a trick taking card game known as Pfeffer. Unfortunately, my math skills are not quite up to the task it would seem. I am trying to find the probability that a card in a player's hand will take a trick if they win the bid and choose the trump suit.

The game is played with a 48 card pinochle deck. Players are dealt 11 cards each, and the remaining four cards go into a blind which the winner of the bid gets to trade cards from before the first trick is played. Cards are valued as follows: 9, 10, J, Q, K, A, 9 of Trump, 10 of Trump, Q of Trump, K of Trump, A of Trump, Left Bower, Right Bower. The Right Bower is the Jacks of the trump suit, and the Left Bower is the Jack of the same color as the trump suit (e.g. if spades is trump, then the Jack of Clubs is the Left Bower). The bidder starts the first trick by leading a card, and the other players must play one at a time, following suit. High card wins, and the winner would lead the next card.

[Probability a card can win a trick with a trump suit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1381560/probability-a-card-can-win-a-trick-with-a-trump-suit) - This question was very helpful, but it does not address the event where the player leads a trump card. It also doesn't consider whether or not an opponent's trump is "covered" by the player's.

**What I am hoping to calculate is the probability that a card in a hand will win a trick, given that the player chooses the trump suit, receives the blind, and plays perfectly.** I will then sum these to determine a rough number of tricks that the hand will take for a given trump suit.

Comment: "...and plays perfectly."  Clarification needed.  Since AI involved, I would surmise that *plays perfectly* is in a **probabilistic** sense.  The alternative interpretation is that *plays perfectly* assumes (in effect) that the cards are **marked**, so that you will always know (for example) whether a finesse or squeeze play will work.  Am I correct that you intend the first interpretation of *plays perfectly*, rather than the second?

Comment: Yes, the first interpretation is correct. I simply mean that the player will not make any mistakes such as playing a 9 when they should have played their Ace of Trump.

Comment: To complicate matters, re previous comment, is the AI (for example) designed to *draw inferences* based on the the bidding of others, as to the chance that a certain finesse will work.  Note that this question may be *nonsensical*; I am assuming that whatever the rules of **Pfeffer** are, it permits (at least to some extent) strategies similar to those used in *bridge*.

Comment: Yes, to a certain extent. The way bidding works in the game is that the person to the left of the dealer bids first. They simply say the number of tricks they think they will take. Bidding proceeds around the table ending with the dealer. The person with the highest bid then names trump. I also forgot to mention that, like Bridge, the game is played in partners; so if you do not have the left bower, your partner may.

Comment: Suggeszion: Generate thousands of random hands for the the others that are consistent with your own hand (and perhaps consistent with tricks already played, i.e., if someone could not follow suit x, ignore random hands were they get s suit x). Simulate the trick for each of these hands and conclude.